# Which way is better accesing android sqlitehelper object from multiple locations?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, multiple-instances

Assume i will store Students, Employees, Teachers etc.

Should i create 3 tables in **one** database or should i create a database for each above object.

- If i choose to use the way one, i need to use one instance of
  sqlitehelper in all parts of my app. So  my classes which dies
  insert, update, delete operations must access that object all the
  time so a little bit extra coding which should be fine.
- If second way, then i don't need to do anything, just create separate
  classes and not having to worry about anything. Or is it? Is creating
  databases for one table or similar conditions good practice? Is it
  bad for phone performance

?

What do you suggest for that?

```
public class StudentDbAdapter{

StudentHelper sh;

public StudentDbAdapter(Context c)
{
    sh = new StudentHelper(c);
}

public Student select(long id)
{
    Student s = new Student();
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = StudentHelper.ID+" = ?";
    Cursor c = db.query(StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,query,new String[]{Long.toString(id)},null,null,null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        s.setId(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.ID)));
        s.setFirstName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.FIRSTNAME)));
        s.setLastName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.LASTNAME)));
        s.setGpa(c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.GPA)));
    }
    c.close();
    return s;
}

public ArrayList<Student> selectSome(int count)
{
    ArrayList<Student> stus = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME+" LIMIT ?";
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,new String[]{Integer.toString(count)});
    if(c.getCount()>0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Student s = new Student();
            s.setId(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.ID)));
            s.setFirstName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.FIRSTNAME)));
            s.setLastName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.LASTNAME)));
            s.setGpa(c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.GPA)));
            stus.add(s);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();

    return stus;
}

public ArrayList<Student>  selectAll()
{
    ArrayList<Student> stus = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c =db.query(StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,null, null,null,null,null);
    if(c.getCount()>0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Student s = new Student();
            s.setId(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.ID)));
            s.setFirstName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.FIRSTNAME)));
            s.setLastName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.LASTNAME)));
            s.setGpa(c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(StudentHelper.GPA)));
            stus.add(s);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return stus;
}
public long insert(Student s)
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO "+StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME+"" +
            "("+StudentHelper.FIRSTNAME+","+StudentHelper.LASTNAME+"," +
            " "+StudentHelper.GPA+") values(?,?,?)";
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);

    stmt.bindString(1,s.getFirstName());
    stmt.bindString(2,s.getLastName());
    stmt.bindDouble(3,s.getGpa());

    s.setId(stmt.executeInsert());
    stmt.clearBindings();

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    return s.getId();
}
public ArrayList<Long> insertMany(ArrayList<Student> stus)
{
    ArrayList<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO "+StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME+"" +
            "("+StudentHelper.FIRSTNAME+","+StudentHelper.LASTNAME+"," +
            " "+StudentHelper.GPA+") values(?,?,?)";
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);

    for(Student s:stus) {

        stmt.bindString(1, s.getFirstName());
        stmt.bindString(2, s.getLastName());
        stmt.bindDouble(3, s.getGpa());

        s.setId(stmt.executeInsert());
        ids.add(s.getId());
        stmt.clearBindings();
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    return ids;
}
public int update(long id,int columnIndex, String value)
{
    String sql = "UPDATE "+StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME+" " +
            "SET "+StudentHelper.COLUMN_NAMES[columnIndex]+" =?  WHERE "+StudentHelper.ID+" = ?";
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();

    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
    stmt.bindDouble(1,Double.parseDouble(value));
    stmt.bindLong(2,id);

    int result = stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    return result;
}

public int delete(long id)
{
    String sql = "DELETE FROM "+StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+StudentHelper.ID+" = ?";
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();

    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
    stmt.bindLong(1,id);

    int result = stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    return result;
}
public int deleteAll()
{
    String sql = "DELETE FROM "+StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME+"";
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();

    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
    int result = stmt.executeUpdateDelete();

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    return result;
}


static class StudentHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HumanInfo";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private Context c;

    /*****************TABLE 1********************/
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student";
    private static final String ID = "_id";
    private static final String FIRSTNAME ="Firstname";
    private static final String LASTNAME ="Lastname";
    private static final String GPA ="GPA";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +"(" +
            ""+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            ""+FIRSTNAME+" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL," +
            ""+LASTNAME+" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL," +
            ""+GPA+" REAL NOT NULL CHECK("+GPA+"< 4)" +
            ");";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME +"";
    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = new String[]{ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,GPA};
    /*****************TABLE 1********************/


    public StudentHelper(Context c)
    {
        super(c,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.c = c;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        try {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(c, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
        try {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(c,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should create a single database only. Three databases are not necessary.
Also you should create a singleton pattern for your database to avoid multiple instances of database and the usual **leak error**

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

Follow the link above to learn more about sqlite and singleton patterns

Answer (score 0):

**Should i create 3 tables in one database or should i create a database for each above object?**
It is always advisable to create one `Database` per project

**If i choose to use the way one, i need to use one instance of sqlitehelper in all parts of my app. So my classes which dies insert, update, delete operations must access that object all the time so a little bit extra coding which should be fine**
Wrong. Just use static sqlitehelper. This will maintain only one instance across all the classes

A word of advice: Given that mobile platforms are super conscious about memory consumption, please take extreme care while creating an instance which is not all necessary.

Comment: Assume, my class calls getWritableDatabase everytime an insert,update etc occurs. Should i assign it to a global variable? Please check my edit on my main post how can i achieve that staticness since it is NESTED class.

Comment: Yes, you can maintain a global variable for `Database`

Comment: Check my edit on main post pls. It is nested class, If i create that nested class for all tables, how to achieve it? Not making nested?

Comment: Make a separate class for `Database` dedicated operations

Comment: Database dedicated you mean create upgrade operations?

Comment: Refactor your class to move `insert`, `delete`, `upgrade` operations to a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

database is collection of tables, why you need more than one database for that simple table? especially if some table have relationship.

Answer (score 0):

> Should i create 3 tables in one database or should i create a database
>   for each above object.

There is no need to create one database for each object, it is even discouraged. You will, most likely, be having relations in the tables and doing so, won't be possible across multiple databases.

About the connection to the database, you should only have one instance, accessed via singleton or, if you prefer, through any class extending application.